# htmlentities() combined with mail() shows nothing when special characters involved

Tags: php, email, html-entities

After a bit of research I cannot find the answer. I'm trying to secure a contact form, but when I'm using the `htmlentities()` function with special characters in my message, the message simply doesn't display. So the text comes from a , when I put only ASCII text, the script works perfectly. At the moment I start using non ASCII characters, there is no content to show...

```
function secure($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlentities($data, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
  return $data;
}
$info = secure($a);
$content = 'bla bla bla'.$info.'bla bla bla';
echo $content;
```

Imagine my text was :

> Ce n’est pas une blague David, ton programme a réellement fonctionné
>   et je suis là. » Dit Prélude. Et suivit une longue explication de
>   Prélude quant à son existence. Comment avait-il fait pour sortir de
>   l’ordinateur de David pour s’installer sur Internet, et de ce fait sur
>   tout les ordinateurs reliés à Internet. Les explications continuèrent
>   pendant une bonne heure. David laissait parler Prélude. Personne
>   n’intervenait. Tout le monde présent, généraux, informaticiens,
>   simples gardes, tous étaient stupéfiaient.

It simply doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by "It simply doesn't work"? No output at all?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not information for us to go on. And what are "special characters" exactly? There's no such thing in general.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get no output at all, except the HTML inside de $content. I get no traces of the content which went trough secure()... By special character, I mean all the chars that are not alphanumeric. like é, », etc...

Comment: Tip: You mean *non-ASCII characters*. What encoding is your text in? Where does it come from?

Comment: Use Notepad++ for example and convert your document, in codification menu, to UTF-8.

Comment: The text comes from a <textarea></textarea>, so I use a $_POST to get it and after I apply the secure() funtion. The coding is supposed to in UTF-8

Comment: How are you ensuring that it's in UTF-8?

Comment: I'm not... How can I be? Even though I'm not a specialist, I don't understand why UTF-8 would change the function :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was an encoding problem... I changed the meta of the HTML page to UTF-8, and magically it worked!!

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Thanks everyone. 
Katsele.